# Persistent use of Jupyter Notebook from remote server

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, remote-access, remote-server, gnu-screen

I connect to a remote server using `ssh -L` but if I close the laptop lid or the connection is lost, the jupyter notebook is disconnected.

After I reconnect to the remote server, the "last" session is lost.

What can be done to make it persistent?
Could `screen` help with it?

Comment: In practice, long running notebooks fail. My suggestion is that you convert the notebook to a script, then run it using screen as @MichaelD suggests. I know this doesn't answer the OP's question, but it will solve their problem

Answer (score 37, accepted):

On the remote server, you should open your jupyter in a `screen` session, it will make it persistent if you lose the connection to the server and resume it.

1. On your computer: `ssh -L xxxx:localhost:yyyy server`.
2. `screen`.
3. `jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=yyyy`. [on remote server]
4. In your browser: `localhost:xxxx`.

To disconnect manually and reconnect:

1. Exit the screen window: `control + a` and then `d`.
2. Disconnect from the server: `control + d`
3. And reconnect `ssh -L xxxx:localhost:yyyy`.
4. Optionally, you can reopen the screen window, though unnecessary, using `screen -r`.
5. Go back to your notebook or reopen `localhost:xxxx`.

Comment: To reconnect, you just have to reconnect to the remote server using `ssh -L xxxx:localhost:yyyy server`. If you want to access the screen where the jupyter is being run, you can do `screen -r`. Note that reconnecting to the remote server is sufficient, you don't have to reopen the screen.

Comment: I use tmux for persistent running of programs.

Comment: what is `xxxx` and `yyyy`. Can you explain about the ports to assign?`

Comment: Basically, you should use an unused port on the local machine (`xxxx`) and the remote machine (`yyyy`). For instance, `xxxx` could be `8888` and `yyyy` could be also `8888`.

Comment: Why do you need to establish a tunnel to the remote server?

Answer (score 11):

The standard usage for persisting Jupyter server sessions is the use of `nohup` and `&`; in your remote server with IP address `xx.xx.xx.xx`:

```
nohup jupyter notebook --no-browser --ip xx.xx.xx.xx --port yyyy &
```

Now, even if you switch off your laptop or lose the connection, you will be always able to reconnect by pointing your browser at `xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy`

Comment: how do chose the `xx.xx.xx.xx`?

Comment: @MichaelD this should be the IP address of your server machine

Comment: I tried it it didn't work for me. (I run `nohup ...` on local machine)

Comment: It didn't worked me. Maybe because server, is in local network... (start with 10.xx)

Comment: @MichaelD shouldn't be an issue - mine, too is in a local net (starts with 192.xx..); did you use `ifconfig` in the server to get its IP?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @BiBi's answer...

Instead of `screen` I could recommend you to take a look at [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux). Especially, if you combine tmux with the [Tmux Plugin Manager](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tpm) and install [Tmux Resurrect](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect), even after reboots of your remote server you will be able to go back to your previous Tmux sessions.

Shortcuts for tmux are somewhat equal to those of screens, just that `control + a` is replaced by `control + b`. Of course, tmux allows you to configure your custom shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

BiBi's answer is correct. But I had cases where my ssh connection terminated unexpectedly and the port forwarding no longer worked when trying to reconnect. Probably there was some dangling process on the remote machine, not sure.

Anyway, in these cases I used `socat` to proxy between two local ports on the remote machine:

```
# jupyter notebook/lab running in screen on port yyyy, then your connection dies...
ssh -L xxxx:localhost:zzzz
socat tcp-listen:zzzz,reuseaddr,fork tcp:localhost:yyyy
```

This way you can avoid restarting jupyter on a different port

Answer (score 0):

Use the nohup command to keep jupyter running even after exiting the shell or terminal. Type the following command in the specified locations.

1. In remote server `nohup jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8085 > my.log 2>&1 < /dev/null &`. This runs jupyter in port 8085 and any stdout would be present in `my.log`
2. In local `ssh -NL 8085:localhost:8085 username@xx.xx.xx.xx`. If port needs to be specified, you can use `ssh -NL 8085:localhost:8085 -p xxxx username@xx.xx.xx.xx`
3. In browser `http://127.0.0.1:8085/`

Sometimes port 8085 may be occupied in the remote server, in such cases try it with another port but make sure you use the same port number in the local while tunneling.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative use `tmux`:

1. Install `tmux` with `conda install tmux` (it may be necessary to install `ncurse` and `libserve`);
2. Create a session `tmux new -s jupyter_session`;
3. This will create and activate a new `tmux` session, which is persistent;
4. Instantiate the jupyter lab server `jupyter lab --no-browser --port=8888` (use the port you're tunneling from);
5. Use `Ctrl+B` and `D` to dettach from the tmux session. This will "close" the session for you, but it will be still running;
6. To re-attach `tmux attach -t jupyter_session`

Additionally: enable automatically saving widget states on jupyter in `Settings > Save Widget States Automatically`