# Run jupyter notebook on GCP without any dependency on my laptop

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, gcp-notebook

I'm currently using GCP to run the Jupyter notebooks on the notebook server provided by Google. Every time I open the notebook server in commandline, it shuts down when there is a network interruption or power outage on my end. I'm very naive on GCP too.

Is there any way that I could run the Ipython notebooks on the server and later collect the results without having to bother about anything else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen this article?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835971/persistent-use-of-jupyter-notebook-from-remote-server   It looks like it may contain a solution?

Comment: @Kolban I'm not getting this one `ssh -L xxxx:localhost:yyyy server`. I think it is a legit solution. Do you have any Idea what's happening here? or can you point me any resources to understand this?

Comment: It might help to look at the "shh -L" command.  I found this one pretty good:

https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using GCP's AI Platform Notebooks?
https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-notebooks/

You can open these notebooks directly in your browser unlike the older Datalab notebooks (no need to SSH).  That should solve your network interruption issues